# Prevent Duplicate Function Method Jquery

Tags: jquery

i'm sorry if my question has been asked before because I did not find the right keywords for my case. So this is my code:

```
<script>

    $('#modal-verify').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var condBefore = $.trim(document.getElementById('condition-raw').innerHTML);
        var condAfter = $('#coll_condition').val();
        var shapeBefore = $.trim(document.getElementById('shape-raw').innerHTML);
        var shapeAfter = $('#coll_shape').val();

        $('#condition-after').html(condAfter);
        $('#shape-after').html(shapeAfter);

        if (condBefore !== condAfter) {
            $('#condition-after').parent('.row-after').addClass('bg-light-yellow');
        } else {
            $('#condition-after').parent('.row-after').removeClass('bg-light-yellow');
        }

        if (shapeBefore !== shapeAfter) {
            $('#shape-after').parent('.row-after').addClass('bg-light-yellow');
        } else {
            $('#shape-after').parent('.row-after').removeClass('bg-light-yellow');
        }
        ---- 6 more same if-else statement ----
    });

</script>
```

I have tried to make a function like this:

```
function (before, after, rowid) {
    if (before !== after) {
        $(rowid).parent('.row-after').addClass('bg-light-yellow');
    } else {
        $(rowid).parent('.row-after').removeClass('bg-light-yellow');
    }
};
```

But but no results. Can anyone give an example or suggestion or maybe i wrote wrong code?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: i try this function (before, after, rowid) but failed to return the result

Comment: Edit your question to include how you called the function as well

Comment: please check my question update.

Comment: Your function has no name, and I can't find a place where you are invoking it, like Anurag asked a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally. After i try my code again using a lot of possibilities. I found the answer. This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    // forgot to give the function name in the previous question
    var highlight = function(before, after, rowid) {
        if (before !== after) {
            $(rowid).parent().addClass('bg-light-yellow');
        } else {
            $(rowid).parent().removeClass('bg-light-yellow');
        }
        // using this to return the result
        return this;
    };

    $('#modal-verify').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var condBefore = $.trim(document.getElementById('condition-raw').innerHTML);
        var condAfter = $('#coll_condition').val();
        var shapeBefore = $.trim(document.getElementById('shape-raw').innerHTML);
        var shapeAfter = $('#coll_shape').val();

        $('#condition-after').html(condAfter);
        $('#shape-after').html(shapeAfter);

        // finally the function is here
        highlight(condBefore, condAfter, '#condition-after');
        highlight(shapeBefore, shapeAfter, '#shape-after');
    });
});
</script>
```

Thank you all, especially to Anurag Srivastava and Yishmeray, for giving me advice and time to check and try my code again.